# Apache Redirect based on directory name

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirects, kohana

I'm trying to use one install of Kohana to manage two separate sites rather than just duplicate the install.  I have directories like this:

```
applications/
   app1/
   app2/
```

The .htaccess I have looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch app1/(.*)$ http://app1.example.com/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*applications/app1.*
RewriteRule .* applications/app1/index.php/$0 [PT]
```

When I go to `app1.example.com` I get a 500 infinite redirect and the URL is `app1.example.com/index.php/index.php/index.php/...`

What I need is for it to look like it's going to `app1.example.com` but behind the scenes it is redirecting to `document_root/applications/app1/index.php`.

I also need this to work for app2 in the same way, but I imagine once I have it working for app1 it will essentially be identical.

If you want to throw in any tips on managing multiple sites with one Kohana install that would help too.

Comment: Why do you have `RedirectMatch` in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Kohana supports multiple sites from one installation, according to the docs:

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/installation

1. Put the system folder somewhere on your server, preferably outside of your webserver's document root.
2. Delete the system folder in your current application.
3. For your application's index.php file, change the $kohana_system variable to the relative or absolute path of where you put the system folder.
4. You can now point all of your applications to this one system folder for easy upgrades. This makes your life a whole lot easier when you have 10+ kohana sites on your server.

Comment: I don't see a kohana_system variable in index.php

Comment: If you're using Kohana 3.x this tutorial will be more up to date: http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/tutorials/sharing-kohana